# Need help with a hibernate criteria query on a simple user management model

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-criteria

i've been working on a user management  which allow users to have permission aside what the roles they belongs to.

so here is the general idea: there is many-to-many bidirectional using jointable between User-Role, Role-Right and there is a many-to-many(double one-to-many) birectional using a class between User-UserSpecialRight and Right-UserSpecialRight the many-to-one side is on the UserSpecialRight side.

Now i'm using Hibernate3.6.1.FINAL+Spring3.0.5.RELEASE+Maven+shiro.using criteria i would like to pull all the rights of a user those for the roles he belogngs to including special rights.
here is the mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", uniqueConstraints = {
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"email"})})
@Component("user")
public class User {

//......
public User() {
    //......
}


@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid.hex")
@Column(name = "user_id", length = 36)
private String id;
@Column(name = "email", length = 150)
private String email;
@Column(name = "password", length = 150)
private String password;
// ...

@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="users")
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

@OneToMany(targetEntity=UserRightAssoc.class,fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="user")
private Set<UserRightAssoc> specialrights = new HashSet<UserRightAssoc>();

//.....
}


 @Entity
 @Table(name = "role")
 @Component("role")
 public class Role {

//....
public Role() {
    //....
}
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
@Column(name = "role_id", length = 36)
private String id;

@Column(name = "role_name")
private String roleName;

//....

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "role_user_map", joinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")},
inverseJoinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")})
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "role_right_map", joinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")},
inverseJoinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name = "right_id")})
private Set<Right> rights = new HashSet<Right>();
//.....
}  


 @Entity
 @Table(name = "rights")
 @Component("right")
 public class Right {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
@Column(name="right_id")
private String id;
@Column(name = "right_name",unique=true)
private String rightName;
@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "rights")
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

@OneToMany(targetEntity=UserRightAssoc.class,fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="right")
private Set<UserRightAssoc> specialrights = new HashSet<UserRightAssoc>();
//...... 
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "user_right_assoc")
@Component("userrightassoc")
public class UserRightAssoc {

//....

@Embeddable
public static class Id implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="user_id")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name="rightId")
    private String rightId;

    public Id(){}

    public Id(String userId, String rightId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.rightId = rightId;
    }

    // equal and hashcode
}

@EmbeddedId
private Id id = new Id();

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dateCreate = new Date();

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity=User.class)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private User user;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="right_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Right right;
```

}

ok that's about the mapping i hope it's not too long. in the RighDAOImpl i have this following method which could not give me the result i wanted.

```
public Set<Right> getRightsByRoleAndEmail(String roleName, String email) {
    try {
        List list = this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(this.getPersistentClass())
                .createAlias("roles", "r")
//              .createAlias("specialrights", "sp")
//              .createAlias("sp.user", "u")
                .add(Restrictions.eq("r.roleName", roleName))
//              .add(Restrictions.eq("u.email", email))
                .list();

        Set<Right> rigths = new HashSet<Right>(list);
        return rigths;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info("Error fecthing righs for a role and user", e);
        return null;
    }

}
```

so the method with the commenting part is successful in my test class but then the special right part is completely ignored.but once the comments are removed it returns null hence the test fails.

at the present moment there is no specialrights for any of the defaults users in my fixtures (import.sql) but i believe the query should still return the rights even if there is no special rights.

here is the query when i turn the criteria method without the comments :

```
 select
    this_.right_id as right1_0_4_,
    this_.date_created as date2_0_4_,
    this_.description as descript3_0_4_,
    this_.last_modified as last4_0_4_,
    this_.right_name as right5_0_4_,
    roles5_.right_id as right2_0_,
    r1_.role_id as role1_,
    r1_.role_id as role1_1_0_,
    r1_.date_created as date2_1_0_,
    r1_.description as descript3_1_0_,
    r1_.last_modefied as last4_1_0_,
    r1_.role_name as role5_1_0_,
    sp2_.rightId as rightId3_1_,
    sp2_.user_id as user2_3_1_,
    sp2_.dateCreate as dateCreate3_1_,
    sp2_.right_id as right4_3_1_,
    right8_.right_id as right1_0_2_,
    right8_.date_created as date2_0_2_,
    right8_.description as descript3_0_2_,
    right8_.last_modified as last4_0_2_,
    right8_.right_name as right5_0_2_,
    u3_.user_id as user1_2_3_,
    u3_.dateCreated as dateCrea2_2_3_,
    u3_.email as email2_3_,
    u3_.full_name as full4_2_3_,
    u3_.lastLogin as lastLogin2_3_,
    u3_.lastModified as lastModi6_2_3_,
    u3_.password as password2_3_ 
from
    rights this_ 
inner join
    role_right_map roles5_ 
        on this_.right_id=roles5_.right_id 
inner join
    role r1_ 
        on roles5_.role_id=r1_.role_id 
inner join
    user_right_assoc sp2_ 
        on this_.right_id=sp2_.right_id 
left outer join
    rights right8_ 
        on sp2_.right_id=right8_.right_id 
inner join
    user u3_ 
        on sp2_.user_id=u3_.user_id 
where
    r1_.role_name=? 
    and u3_.email=?
```

So is there anything that i'm leaving out not seeing , not considering? anything aside that method works fine.Can anyone shed some lights?

thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return a User even if they don't have Special Rights, then you can't query on it, as if there is nothing there, you won't get anything back.  Adding the `Restrictions.eq` creates this situation for you.

Instead, remove the Special Rights section from your query and initialize the association once the User object is returned.

```
List<User> list = this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class)
            .createAlias("roles", "r")
            .add(Restrictions.eq("r.roleName", roleName))
            .list();
for (User u : list) {
   if(u.getSpecialRights() != null) {
      u.getSpecialRights().size();  // loads the special rights if they are not null
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, make sense.Currently i do all this separately in a service method where it's transactional. so i pull, rights for the role, and then pull specialright for the user.

Answer (score 0):

to get the records even when there are no special rights you need a left join

```
List list = this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(this.getPersistentClass())
    .createAlias("roles", "r")
    .createAlias("specialrights", "sp", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
    .createAlias("sp.user", "u", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("r.roleName", roleName))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("u.email", email))
    .list();
```